# How to change background color of a navigation bar?

Tags: css

I am trying to write code to change the background color of a navigation bar using HTML and CSS but can not seem to come up with anything that works.

Below is the example of the code requirements: For this `<nav>` element, write the following styling:

- Background color of `rgb(179,193,176)`.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide your code, suppose you have the following navigation bar:

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</nav>
```

To set the background color of this element you simply write into your CSS file:

```css
.navbar {
   background-color: rgb(179,193,176);
}
```